# Don't know how to return the final result of a recursion loop

Tags: python, recursion

I was solving a problem on Codewars involving recursion and I've never really done it before but kinda understand the concept. Im not really good at math stuff so it probably explains why I cant wrap my head around this. Essentially I think I kinda did the loop right I just dont know how to print the final value. Anyway heres my code:

```py
def digital_root(n):
    newn = 0
    list = [int(x) for x in str(n)]
    if len(list) >= 2:
        for i in range(len(list)):
            newn += list[i]
        digital_root(newn)
    return n

print(digital_root(1234)
```

output:

```py
1234
```

Comment: The result of the inner call must be `return`ed explicitly by the outer function.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thankyou for your reply. I understand I'm supposed to do that but I don't really know. I tried making newn a global but got a typeval error

Comment: You return the result from a recursive call to your function *the same way that you would return the result from calling any other function*.

Comment: You should show the alternative try and the full error message in the question.

Comment: There is no such thing as "a recursion loop". If you want to loop, use a loop - such as `while`. Recursion is a different way of thinking about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
def digital_root(n):
    newn = 0
    list = [int(x) for x in str(n)]
    if len(list) >= 2:
        for i in range(len(list)):
            newn += list[i]
        return digital_root(newn) # You need to return it over here
    return n

print(digital_root(1234))
```

Comment: this outputs `1234` again...

Comment: @r_33 no this outputs 1

Comment: hmm wait so I dont understand why this reoccurs.  When your write `return digital_root(newn)` where does that output go back to?

Comment: then it will return the value that will be obtained by `digital_root(newn)`

for example in 1234

first it sums 1+2+3+4 = 10   
then again sums 1+0 = 1
and return final value that is 1

Comment: Oh I see. Thankyou. Is the way I went about solving this problem a bad/dumb way of doing so?

Comment: No this is a really common mistake that probably everybody faces while beginig with programmin. If my answer helped please upvote it .